# How to associate a function's input arguments with its return type to leverage autosuggest features

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to link the arguments types and the return type of a function together using generics. I alread found a solution but I find it sub-optimal, since I have a feeling that it can be done better.

Basically, I have the following function:

```
function postCommand<T extends AvailableCommands>(
    commandName: T,
    commandArguments: ArgumentType<T>
): Observable<PayloadType<T>> {
    return httpClient.post<PayloadType<T>>(`/command/${commandName}`, commandArguments);
}
```

combined with the following (sample) definitions:

```
type AvailableCommands =
    | 'create-group'
    | 'create-post';


type ArgumentType<T extends AvailableCommands> = T extends 'create-group'
    ? CreateGroupArguments
    : T extends 'create-post'
    ? CreatePostArguments
    : never;

type PayloadType<T extends AvailableCommands> = T extends 'create-group'
    ? CreateGroupPayload
    : T extends 'create-post'
    ? CreatePostPayload
    : never;
```

Note: `*Arguments` and `*Payload` are defined outside of the scope als plain interfaces for objects. For example with keys `groupId` and `body` for `CreatePostArguments`.
`httpClient` is also defined outside of the scope (it's basically the Angular7 HTTP Client)

The above code allows me to use the function `postCommand` with autosuggestions for the input variable `commandName` and autosuggestions for `commandArguments` based on which `commandName` I typed in. The `commandPayload` is also inferred when I subscribe on the returned observable.

Now, using conditional types is ugly and not easily understood by other developers.

This lead me to trying to find another way, where I stumbled upon [

This changes the code as follows:

```
function postCommand<T extends AvailableCommands>(
    commandName: T,
    commandArguments: CommandMap[T]['arguments']
): Observable<CommandMap[T]['payload']> {
    return httpClient.post<CommandMap[T]['payload']>(`/command/${commandName}`, commandArguments);
}

interface CommandMap {
    'create-group': { arguments: CreateGroupArguments; payload: CreateGroupPayload };
    'create-post': { arguments: CreatePostArguments; payload: CreatePostPayload };
}
```

Now, this already looks more readable and has the same effect. I still have autosuggestions. The only caveat is: If I omit `create-post` from the `CommandMap` interface, the compiler does not mind. This is a problem with both of the above implementations.

This is mostly what I wanted, except for the caveat I mentioned. So, my question now is:

Is there a way to make the compiler mind the fact that I did not define mappings for all `AvailableCommands` in `CommandMap`, and still have autosuggestion for the arguments and the return type of `postCommand`?

(I have created a [Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=3.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAggbgQwJYBsECMUQMIHsC2+CAdgCYDOUAvFAOQDGAThAsBALRi7nC1QA+dJizbsA5o1wBXMLQDcAKAVJibRgDME9aHkIlSAWQRgoAbwVRLQ5qw4TpsgFxmoCRmKn4Iq8s+w22AHFJGRh3T29gcjkoMAQQFFwEUj8AiGCHAAV4xOSoAF9FK2sRDi4eWmdTV3CvH1TSzO5gMI86qJi4hKSUqH9G5uzuvMKFfKUVNU1tPrSMmSHc0jMLK3xmgFViJABHKQgAaQgQZx5GFTFFceVVCA0tHTSmnkWeleKsHi3d-aOTqDOFyuE1u9xm-Vs8zArQiPneVmICC8p2A52Il1Wli8+HQd18ANRFwA2gBdYE3KYPWYDHgw9qUczFewyACSvUB6KKVnQuFI-w5GOu6ikxHowCQuGIsWaAB4ACoAPgAFFJGCgUWixAAaGpifEkEAASmcBvhlmYwFVUtMoyFIrFEql5WAuiIZHlUAgAA82GRKPBkGhMDgCG6KMrMVB6KH9AA5JEQZxyrWR6N6Mh0yL4136IxgIlyklE2huNpZ2gkhTGvoxsh5gtF2hdJYVs1QC1W6U8GU5uvGBvF5s9CvKgAGAHo02HxwASUxTuMJ-KjnULjO1LOG4FAA) with my latest version, and a mock implementation of `post` and the TypeScript version I am using for my project)

### Edit:

The overall best answer for me was hidden in plain sight:

I basically only use one type now

```
export interface CommandMap {
    [index: string]: { arguments: any; payload: any };
    'create-group': { arguments: CreateGroupArguments; payload: CreateGroupPayload };
    'create-post': { arguments: CreatePostArguments; payload: CreatePostPayload };
}
```

and the function call:

```
public postCommand<T extends keyof CommandMap>(
    commandName: T,
    commandArguments: CommandMap[T]['arguments']
): Observable<CommandMap[T]['payload']> {
    return this.httpClient.post<CommandMap[T]['payload']>(`/command/${commandName}`, commandArguments);
}
```

The generic now extends `keyof CommandMap`. Since the `CommandMap` already has all the definitions for my Commands, I did not need an additional `AvailableCommands` Type.

All the AutoSuggestion features are still available, and the errors are in the right place (the interface definition itself, if at all)

Comment: But the compiler does mind quite a bit if you comment out `create-post` it just that the errors occur on the function. since `CommandMap[T]` will not be valid since `T` is not s key (or subset of keys of `CommandMap`)

Comment: That's correct, I did not notice that. The only issue is the fact that the error is opaque in nature. It works, but I reckon it would not be clear for anyone who looks at the code later.

So, combined with what @jcalz proposed, I think I can have both errors and some indication on what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a compiler error if the keys of `CommandMap` don't match up with `AvailableCommands` you can make that happen in a separate line:

```
type VerifyCommandMap<
  // if the next line is an error, CommandMap has extra keys
  K extends AvailableCommands = keyof CommandMap,
  // if the next line is an error, CommandMap is missing some keys
  L extends keyof CommandMap = AvailableCommands 
  > = true;
```

Basically you're forcing the default parameters to satisfy generic constraints that they only satisfy if `AvailableCommands` is the same as `keyof CommandMap`.

Does that help?

Comment: It helps, it's still kind of opaque, and _weird_, but it definitely works and I think I can go with that.